# Do we need to create a copy of a variable inside a crtitical section?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

```cpp
void Animal::notifyEatingInitiated() {
    log.debug(TAG, "notifyEatingInitiated called");
     
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    auto observers = m_observers;
     
    for (const auto& observer : observers) {
        observer->notifyEatingInitiated();
    }
}
```

I am going through a c++ tutorial and here I see inside the critical section we are creating a copy of instance variable `m_observers` and then iterate over it.

Is it necessary to create a copy of `m_observers`

Doesn't critical section locks the variable outside the current scope(here `m_observers`) for modification?

Comment: No, it's not necessary. Unless `notifyEatingInitiated()` somehow modifies the list, but that's unrelated to the critical section.

Comment: If the loop might be expensive, and you want other threads to access the original list while your shown code is running (and all references or pointers are guaranteed to stay valid) then you can create a copy and unlock the mutex right after the copying.

Comment: Add a scope : `{ std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex); auto observers = m_observers; }`  this will unlock the mutex right after the copy. There will however be a race condition if an observer unsubsribes (which also should be managed by the same m_mutex) then it might still get an update

Comment: No, such a copy is merely a useless performance hit. The copy would make sense if the `lock` was released right afterwards, so that the loop could work in parallel with additions / removals of observers. Which might be undesirable, because the whole class would then need an RCU-like mechanism to ensure that (e.g.) a newly added observer is guaranteed to take effect at some point. Also, observers would have to be pointed at using `std::shared_ptr` (with another performance hit) to make the observers vector snapshot work. Anyhow, there is no point in copying `m_observers` in the case shown.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

#### Under normal circumstances, the copy is unnecessary

It's not necessary  from a thread-safety perspective.
There are a few possibilities:

1. `m_observers` is properly guarded by a `std::mutex` everywhere, so it would be equally safe to simply loop over `m_observers`
2. `m_observers` is not properly guarded by `std::mutex` in other locations, in which case calling the copy constructor in `auto observers = m_observers;` is a data-race anyway

In either case, it doesn't make sense to copy `m_observers` for the purpose of thread-safety.

#### Copying could be useful from a performance perspective

It might make sense to write:

```cpp
auto observers = [this] {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    return m_observers;
}(); // immediately invoked lambda expression (IILE)

for (const auto& observer : observers) {
    observer->notifyEatingInitiated();
}
```

If `notifyEatingInitiated()` takes a long time, and copying `m_observers` is cheap, then this would be a major improvement because it limits the time spent in the critical section.
Your example doesn't even attempt to reap the benefits of copying `observers`, so it's more likely that the author of the tutorial misunderstands the topic, or has made a mistake.

#### But what if `notifyEatingInitiated()` modifies `m_observers`?

As commenter @HolyBlackCat has pointed out, it could be that `notifyEatingInitiated()` modifies `m_observers`.
In such case *it is* necessary to copy `m_observers` to avoid modifying the container during iteration.

While this would be surprising and bug-prone design, it would be necessary to write the code *exactly* like the author has done in your example.

Comment: The performance perspective only helps when combined with proper lifetime management of the observers (i.e. `m_observers` would need to contain `std::shared_ptr`s to observers, not raw pointers). At that point, considering how costly a `std::shared_ptr` copy is, the performance advantage becomes uncertain. Also, a mechanism like RCU would be needed when an `Animal` class user needs a guarantee that their newly added observer will take effect on all future events. Without holding the mutex during observer execution, the only option is to wait for >=one RCU grace period after adding an observer.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case whole code is broken. Each thread creates by copy some irrelevant observers and notifies them while `m_observers` will never be notified.

```
void Animal::notifyEatingInitiated() {
         log.debug(TAG, "notifyEatingInitiated called");
     
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex); 
         auto observers = m_observers; //observers at this point are copy of m_observers not refference to m_observers
     
         for (const auto& observer : observers) {
             observer->notifyEatingInitiated();
         }
     }
```

Such use of copy is irrelevant and kills code completely. Copy is cheaper then construction so should used since faster in appropriate places. Copy of object is by no means an alias of initial object it's totally new object. Read about shallow and deep copy.  Thread safety not guarantied as mentioned above. For thread safety always wrap protected with protection and expose methods like `safe_notify_all()` where both `m_mutex` and `m_observers` are private members of wrapper.